# I want to sent my app to a number of testers. Can I do this without submitting it to the AppleStore or alike?

Tags: ios, share

I want to sent my app to a number of testers, without submitting it to the applestore. Are there any options? Thanks.

And how people do this remotely, if they can't attach tester's ipad to their Mac?

Comment: Use testflightapp.com  and learn about the certificate process.  This has been asked 100 times so just google!

Comment: Thanks for your input, btw,  from google I got a few answers to use applestore (?)

Comment: Such kind of answers/questions should rather make a golden collection than get phase out and reappear, otherwise  the whole StackOverflow just pipelining good staff with no knowledge accumulation whatsoever. Maybe I'm wrong and someone already put thought into this?

Comment: I utterly agree with you, @matrix3003.  it's the obvious way forward.  in 5 years, all QA will work as you describe.  it's the next revolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add their device's UDID to portal then create an Ad-Hoc Provisioning Profile then Sign your app with that Ad-Hoc Profile and send the IPA file to those test users.

else use https://www.testflightapp.com/dashboard/ to upload IPA file and notify them.

Answer (score -1):

Go with a Enterprise profile + certificate and then create a build with provisioning profile.

So whichever device ids, have been attached to that certificate can install your application, no other can install it.

Then distribute your ipa file to all your testers.

For more details: [Apple App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: it's incredibly unusual you would use an enterprise cert for this.  of the 800,000 apps, 799,999 are tested using testFlightApp.com in the normal way.